# Remove excessive relationships in tree-like structure

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table includes two fields with nodes_id and one field with relationships (Only one variant: 'Include')

[Remove relationships marked red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t5TP.png)

I need to remove excessive relationships in case there are any interim node between 2 other nodes

Table with examples

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (
node_id_1 varchar (255),
node_id_2 varchar (255),
relationship varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO relationships
VALUES ('node_1', 'node_2', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_3', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_4', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_5', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_6', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_7', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_8', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_9', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_10', 'Include'),
       ('node_1', 'node_11', 'Include'),
       ('node_3', 'node_5', 'Include'),
       ('node_4', 'node_5', 'Include'),
       ('node_6', 'node_7', 'Include'),
       ('node_8', 'node_9', 'Include'),
       ('node_9', 'node_10', 'Include');
);
```

Comment: Some sample data and the expected result would be helpful.

Comment: @Jeremy thank you for the reply. I've edited the initial post. I expect to delete relationships 1-5, 1-7, 1-9, 8-10, 8-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test data doesn't seem to match your test diagram (there are no 8-10 or 8-11 links, but there is a 1-10).  You can use a recursive CTE to follow the paths.  This part of the query is almost identical to the example in the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html although we won't use the cycle part of the query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(node_id_1, node_id_2, depth, path, cycle) AS (
 SELECT node_id_1, node_id_2, 1, ARRAY[node_id_1::text, node_id_2::text], false
 FROM relationships
 UNION ALL
 SELECT r.node_id_1, r.node_id_2, sg.depth + 1, path || r.node_id_2::text, r.node_id_1 = ANY(PATH)
 FROM relationships r, search_graph sg
 WHERE r.node_id_1 = sg.node_id_2 --AND NOT cycle
)
select * from search_graph;
 node_id_1 | node_id_2 | depth |              path              | cycle
-----------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------+-------
 node_1    | node_2    |     1 | {node_1,node_2}                | f
 node_1    | node_3    |     1 | {node_1,node_3}                | f
 node_1    | node_4    |     1 | {node_1,node_4}                | f
 node_1    | node_5    |     1 | {node_1,node_5}                | f
 node_1    | node_6    |     1 | {node_1,node_6}                | f
 node_1    | node_7    |     1 | {node_1,node_7}                | f
 node_1    | node_8    |     1 | {node_1,node_8}                | f
 node_1    | node_9    |     1 | {node_1,node_9}                | f
 node_1    | node_10   |     1 | {node_1,node_10}               | f
 node_1    | node_11   |     1 | {node_1,node_11}               | f
 node_3    | node_5    |     1 | {node_3,node_5}                | f
 node_4    | node_5    |     1 | {node_4,node_5}                | f
 node_6    | node_7    |     1 | {node_6,node_7}                | f
 node_8    | node_9    |     1 | {node_8,node_9}                | f
 node_9    | node_10   |     1 | {node_9,node_10}               | f
 node_3    | node_5    |     2 | {node_1,node_3,node_5}         | t
 node_4    | node_5    |     2 | {node_1,node_4,node_5}         | t
 node_6    | node_7    |     2 | {node_1,node_6,node_7}         | t
 node_8    | node_9    |     2 | {node_1,node_8,node_9}         | t
 node_9    | node_10   |     2 | {node_1,node_9,node_10}        | t
 node_9    | node_10   |     2 | {node_8,node_9,node_10}        | t
 node_9    | node_10   |     3 | {node_1,node_8,node_9,node_10} | t
(22 rows)
```

We can self join the results of this query to pick out the rows where the beginning and end of the path on one side of the join match node_id_1 and node_id_2 on the other side and where the depth is less:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(node_id_1, node_id_2, depth, path, cycle) AS (
 SELECT node_id_1, node_id_2, 1, ARRAY[node_id_1::text, node_id_2::text], false
 FROM relationships
 UNION ALL
 SELECT r.node_id_1, r.node_id_2, sg.depth + 1, path || r.node_id_2::text, r.node_id_1 = ANY(PATH)
 FROM relationships r, search_graph sg
 WHERE r.node_id_1 = sg.node_id_2 --AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT distinct sg1.node_id_1, sg1.node_id_2
FROM search_graph sg1
JOIN search_graph sg2 ON sg1.node_id_1 = sg2.path[1] AND sg1.node_id_2 = sg2.path[array_length(sg2.path, 1)]
  AND sg1.depth < sg2.depth;
 node_id_1 | node_id_2
-----------+-----------
 node_1    | node_10
 node_1    | node_5
 node_1    | node_7
 node_1    | node_9
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only issue that needs to be resolved now is: column 4 has type character varying(1000)[] in non-recursive term but type character varying[] overall Hint: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type. I know this happens due to type modifiers in a recursive function, but how can I handle this?

Comment: I added a few casts to text that should fix that issue.